# Why does my USB hard drive pause operation when my Linux account times out and locks?

Tags: linux, usb

***Why does my USB hard drive pause operation when my Linux account times out and locks?***

Whenever my Linux desktop screen locks, it seems to pause operation on whatever its doing, and continue once I unlock the screen.

***Here's my exact situation:***

Yesterday I replaced a 1TB drive from my VMware ESXi Host, and had placed said drive in my external USB drive enclosure for a full dd wipe. (command used: `dd if=/dev/urandom | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M` )

The above command wipes the drive with random data and the "pv" gives a visual representation of the progress on screen. I've used this many times, but usually with internal storage. Without progress, that "pv" provides, the dd command is so mysterious with how things are going. If you haven't used "pv" before you can install it, its not a standard command on any of the distributions of Linux, that I've ever used. (ex. `sudo apt install -y pv`)

I started the wipe and walked away. I then later went back into the room to check on the progress and I found my screen was locked, as expected, and the activity light on the enclosure was solid, and assumed the process had completed normally. The PC was awake, it wasn't sleeping itself, just the lock screen was up. I put in my password and unlocked the screen, and suddenly the activity light on the USB enclosure began to flash again. I assumed it had finished its dd wipe and was just sleeping and I woke it up. However that was not the case, the terminal window showed that it had continued on with the process. This repeated over and over again, I could not walk away from the computer, or the operation would pause every single time the lock screen appeared. WHY?

I already attempted to change the power level from "auto" to "on" with the following command but the same result, each and every time the account lock screen appears, the USB activity stops and then resumes once unlocked.

***Here's the command I used to change the power level:***

`echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level >/dev/null`

I also left the machine on overnight and 8 hours later the progress was the same, about the exact amount of wipe that could be done in the 10 or so minutes before the lock screen appeared and as soon as I woke the system back up it resumed the dd wipe.

I didn't even think the dd wipe could be paused like that on its own. I can fully understand if the drive decided to sleep if it had nothing going on, but an active wipe, I would think, would keep the drive awake.

Does anyone have an explanation as to why, and/or a way to prevent this from happening?

I'm going to try and just internally install the drive into a bench system, and see if I can get it to finish without me needing to babysit it the entire time, ensuring the screen doesn't lock from inactivity.

```
uname -a
(Linux kalidesk 6.0.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.7-1kali1 (2022-11-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux)
```

Comment: Note: Any modern implementation of `dd` supports `status=progress`.